# GoogleMaps list results

Tags: android

I've been trying to make a nearby places app, and I've been wondering if there is any function that shows the results like on the image down below:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the results like in the image above, you can create a custom view that will display each place informations, then use a recyclerview and an adapter. Then you can make a nearby search request based on the location of your choice and parse the results.

You can find more explainations about nearby search request at this link:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

About recyclerview, you can check: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

and about the adapter:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter

You'll find many other posts here on stackoverflow that will explain the use of the recyclerview, and I think, they will be helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks ! that was exactly what i was looking for